# expressing oracle query in more efficient manner

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below oracle query which is fetching the results and bringing the results in a perfect manner , but please advise can i write the below query in more efficient manner

```
SELECT DISTINCT PSNETWORKID
FROM JGH
INNER JOIN IDF
ON IDF.PSIDFFIID         = JGH.PSNETWORKID
WHERE (JGH.zzACQUIRERID IN
  (SELECT DISTINCT pstdftermid FROM YUI WHERE pstdftermownid =111111
  )
OR zzACQUIRERID = 111111);
```

Comment: The query only describes which data should be selected; the choosen **execution plan** is relevant for the *efficiency* of the execution. Pls, post the [execution plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975406/how-to-describe-performance-issue-in-relational-database?answertab=active#tab-top) and **decribe the problem** you encouter. *If there is no problem, do not try to create one;)*

Comment: The `distinct` in the sub-query is useless

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be your query:

```
select distinct PSNETWORKID 
from JGH INNER JOIN
     IDF 
     on IDF.PSIDFFIID = JGH.PSNETWORKID 
where JGH.zzACQUIRERID in (select pstdftermid 
                           from YUI
                           where pstdftermownid = 111111
                          ) or
      zzACQUIRERID = 111111;
```

First, `select distinct` is usually a bad idea.  Let me assume it is unique in one of the tables -- say `JFH`.  Then, I would approach this as:

```
select jgh.PSNETWORKID 
from JGH 
where exists (select 1
              from IDF
              where IDF.PSIDFFIID = JGH.PSNETWORKID
             ) and
      (exists (select 1
               from YUI
               where JGH.zzACQUIRERID = YUI.pstdftermid and YUI.pstdftermownid = 111111
             ) or
       jgh.zzACQUIRERID = 111111
      );
```

I would then recommend indexes on `IDF(PSIDFFIID)` and `YUI(pstdftermid, pstdftermownid)`.

Answer (score 0):

By "efficient" do you mean succinct or quicker run time? Generally you want to use EXIST rather than IN.

```
SELECT distinct PSNETWORKID  
  FROM JGH 
 INNER 
  JOIN IDF 
    ON IDF.PSIDFFIID= JGH.PSNETWORKID 
 WHERE EXISTS  
          ( SELECT 1 
              FROM (SELECT pstdftermid conditionField
                      FROM YUI 
                     UNION ALL
                    SELECT 111111 AS conditionField
                      FROM dual
                   ) TMP
             WHERE JGH.zzACQUIRERID = TMP.conditionField
          );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is tested on Oracle 11.2.0.2.0. Note that your version is relevant here, because some *very good* advise for older version could be irrelevant for newer version.

This is the execution plan I got with your query and generated data

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name        | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |             |     1 |    39 |       |   437   (1)| 00:00:06 |
|   1 |  HASH UNIQUE         |             |     1 |    39 |       |   437   (1)| 00:00:06 |
|*  2 |   FILTER             |             |       |       |       |            |          |
|*  3 |    HASH JOIN         |             |   108K|  4142K|  2656K|   436   (1)| 00:00:06 |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| IDF         |   108K|  1380K|       |    46   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| JGH         |   109K|  2786K|       |    62   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN  | PSTDFTERMID |   725 | 18850 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("JGH"."ZZACQUIRERID"=111111 OR  EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM "YUI" "YUI" 
              WHERE "PSTDFTERMOWNID"=111111 AND "PSTDFTERMID"=:B1))
   3 - access("IDF"."PSIDFFIID"="JGH"."PSNETWORKID")
   6 - access("PSTDFTERMID"=:B1 AND "PSTDFTERMOWNID"=111111)
```

So, one possible advise to make your query more "effective" could be **re-order the OR predicate** and put the subquery on the second place to avoid execution the subquery if the predicate `zzACQUIRERID = 111111` is true. *But if you see the the `filter` on line 2 above, this is* **done for you by Oracle**.

Next advice is to **use `EXISTS` instead of the the `IN` operator**. The same is true if you look in the second part of the `filter` - the query is **rewriten and uses `EXISTS`**.

So the most important part is (and I guess this is relevant to your query if it never ends - which you don't  mentioned) to have the index on `YUI(pstdftermid, pstdftermownid)`. This gives you the index access in the line 6.

If you see in this place something like

```
|*  8 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL | YUI       |  10000 |    100 |  10000 |00:00:01.82 |     131K|       |       |          |

   8 - filter(("PSTDFTERMID"=:B1 AND "PSTDFTERMOWNID"=111111))
```

this would lead to very ineffective execution, making one **full table scan** for each `PSTDFTERMID` key.

So my advice is *in the first step* check the excution plan and be sure there is the mentioned index.

Rewrite the query only if you want to *force* Oracle to take a different execution plan, not based on the *best practices* from the past versions.